# How to use repositories?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I am new to Ubuntu and ROS, so I have a beginner question :

How do I use repositories ?
For example I am interested in using the **cob_environments stack**.
on the ros wiki I have found that this stack belongs to **Source: git https://github.com/ipa320/cob_environments.git.**

the question is what I do next ?

And also what I do when the stack located on SNV, for example : **Source: svn https://utexas-art-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stacks/velodyne**

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50212/how-to-use-repositories-?/) by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 192 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say you want to install the first stack you mentioned: `cob_environments`.  Assuming you are on an officially supported version of Ubuntu and [your repositories are setup correctly](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu), you could first check if there are pre-built binaries available. For the `cob_environments` package, I could run

```
apt-cache search ros.*cob
```

in a terminal.  On my system, I can see that there is a package called `ros-fuerte-cob-environments`.  I could install this using `apt-get`, and the stack (plus all of its dependencies would be installed).  For many users, if prebuilt binaries are available, this is the way to go.

In general when a stack or package is not available through your package manager you need to do the following things:

1. Get a local copy of the source code, and make sure it is in your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`
2. Check that you have all of the dependencies for that stack/package installed
3. Install any missing dependencies.  Tools like `apt-get` and `rosdep` are very useful for this!
4. Compile the code

For the `cob-environments` stack, the only dependency that you likely don't have (assuming you have a "full-desktop" install of ROS) is `cob_common`  This can be seen by looking at the dependencies link on the right side of [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cob_environments#).  I'm going to walk you through installing `cob_environments`.

1. To get a copy of the source code, we will use `git`.  So first navigate to a directory that is on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, then run this command (you will need git installed)

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ipa320/cob_environments
   ```
2. We are going to use `rosmake` to try and build this package.

   ```
   rosmake cob_environments
   ```
3. If you don't have `cob_common`, this will error out, and you will need to clone `cob_common` and build that before you can build `cob_environments`.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/ipa320/cob_common
   rosmake cob_common
   ```
4. You should now be able to re-run `rosmake cob_environments`.  If the process completes successfully, you should now have the stack successfully installed!

Note the process with SVN or CVS or Mercurial would be basically the same, but the actual commands for obtaining a copy of the repository would be slightly different.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmeltz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2498/dmeltz/) on 2012-12-12**:
Thank you jarvisschultz. it works perfectly!
very detailed and useful answer !

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-12-12**:
No problem!  @KruseT's answer is not quite complete, but he definitely points out some useful tools.  If you are using ROS long-term, checking out the link he posted at some time is probably worth it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create a development environment using rosws:
http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/doc/api/rosinstall/html/

Then do this:

```
$ roslocate info cob_environments | rosws merge -
$ rosws update
```

this will take care of the details. The same goes for velodyne:

```
$ roslocate info velodyne | rosws merge -
$ rosws update
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3